# deploy Rshiny application connected to an sql database

Tags: sql, r, database, shiny, shinydashboard

Please how can i deploy my shiny application developed with R studio and connected an sql database. I created the mysql database on a local server (wampserver) and the application connects to it perfectly but i have to deploy it with the database.

Comment: is your question how to make the database accessible to the Shiny application when you host the Shiny application on another server (besides your local)?

Comment: Actually i used to deploy my shiny apps with shiniapp.io but do not understand how to host my sql database with which  the app can communicate and store data

Answer (score 1):

Consider deploying your sql database in the same place that you will be deploying your application.  Otherwise, you will need to look into options for exposing your database in such a way that your app will be able to access it.

For example, you could deploy both the database and app on an AWS EC2 instance.  Alternatively, you could deploy the database to an RDS instance and connect to it remotely with your app on EC2.  Those examples are only pertinent to Amazon resources, but the logic applies regardless of your platform.